# Displaying form validation errors in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having some difficulty getting my nested rails form to display validation errors in the view

Controller:

```
class RentersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_renter, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :get_rental

  def get_rental
    @rental = Rental.find(params[:rental_id])
  end

    ...

  # GET /renters/new
  def new
    @renter = Renter.new
  end

  ...

  def create
    @renter = @rental.renters.new(renter_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @renter.save
        format.html { redirect_to rental_renters_path(@rental), notice: 'Renters were successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @renter }
      else
        puts @renter.errors.full_messages
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @renter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Model

```
class Renter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rental

  validates :name,      presence:  { message: "..." }
  validates :height,    presence:  { message: "..." }
  validates :weight,    presence:  { message: "..." }
  validates :shoeSize,  presence:  { message: "..." }

end
```

_form partial being rendered in View

```
<div class="rental-forms-container sixteen wide column">
  <%= form_for([@rental, @renter], remote: true, :html => { class: "renter-form ui form", id: "base-form" }) do |f| %>

    <div class="fields">

      ...

    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="ui warning message">
  ...
  <ul class="list">
    <% @renter.errors.messages.values.each do |message| %>
      <%  message.each do |m| %>
        <li><%= m %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

...

    <%= link_to 'continue with booking', rental_renters_path, remote: true, class: 'ui teal submit button', id: 'submitRenterForms' %>

</div>
```

Console

```
Processing by RentersController#create as JS
Processing by RentersController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "renter"=>{"name"=>"", "height"=>"", "weight"=>"", "wetsuit_style"=>"Adult Womens", "shoeSize"=>"", "rental_id"=>""}, "rental_id"=>"109"}
  Parameters: {"rental_id"=>"109"}
  Rental Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "rentals".* FROM "rentals" WHERE "rentals"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 109], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rental Load (5.5ms)  SELECT  "rentals".* FROM "rentals" WHERE "rentals"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 109], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Name Let us know the name of each renter so we can customize your experience
Height Let us know the height of each renter so we can properly size your wetsuits
Weight Let us know the weight of each renter so we can properly size your wetsuits
Shoesize Let us know the shoe size of each renter so everyone gets the right surf booties
  Rendering renters/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered renters/_form.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered renters/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_following_menu.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar_menu.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 73.8ms | ActiveRecord: 14.0ms)


   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "renters" WHERE "renters"."rental_id" = $1  [["rental_id", 109]]
  Rendering renters/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Charge Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "charges".* FROM "charges" WHERE "charges"."rental_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["rental_id", 109], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered rentals/_info.html.erb (11.0ms)
  Renter Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "renters".* FROM "renters" WHERE "renters"."rental_id" = $1  [["rental_id", 109]]
  Rendered charges/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered renters/index.html.erb within layouts/application (37.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_following_menu.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar_menu.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 265ms (Views: 134.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
```

The validation errors are outputting to the terminal but they are not appearing in the view.

I have tried using the flash and session hashes to pass them to the view but to no avail. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `<%= @renter.errors.messages %>` in your view. You will see the list of errors on your html page if they are present.

Comment: Before this, try replacing `<% @renter.errors.messages.values.each do |message| %>` with `<%= @renter.errors.messages.values.each do |message| %>` and see if it works.

Comment: I tried all of those combinations and more. In the view
`<%= @renter.errors.messages.values.each do |message| %>`
renders a hash with blank values. What I don't understand is why I can output the errors to the console before the controller renders :new but after in the view they are blank. @JagdeepSingh

Answer (score 1):

When using form_for (or if you're now using form_with) pay attention to whether remote or local is set to true. Local uses the browser's normal submission mechanism, while remote uses Ajax. When using remote (as indicated above), the page will not render in the "normal" fashion, as expected.

The Rails documentation has more details: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html